# How do I create a separate plot for each patient showing their 'Order Amount' and 'Order Quantity' against 'Order Time' variable?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning

The issue that I am facing right now is that the code is returning a plot that showed the most recent data that matches with the user's input date. I wanted to study the data together, thus I wanted a trend in the plot instead of a single horizontal line for the most current data. However, it is not displaying the merged data of the past data that corresponds with the same 'Patient ID' and the most recent data. I wanted to create two plots, one of the plots is 'Order Amount' against 'Order Time' and the other 'Order Quantity' against 'Order Time' .

[image: img1]

The data is grouped in this way:

[image: img2]

There are four main parts that the code wanted to address:

1. Matching the most recent data with the input date, which I have already filtered the dataframe based on the input date.
2. Matching the same ID of previous data with the most recent data and stringing the data together: To achieve this, we need to identify the most recent data for each patient ID and then merge it with the previous data for the same patient ID.
3. Picking the rows with the highest value for 'Order Amount' and 'Order Quantity' between the two rows sharing the same 'Patient ID' and 'Order Time': After merging the recent data with the previous data, we can compare the values of Order Amount and Order Quantity for each patient ID and select the rows with the highest values.  - I am stuck at this stage :)

For example, rows 27 and 28 show that the 'Order Amount' and 'Order Quantity' are, respectively, 659.8 and 21 and 671.677 and 13 for row 28. In this scenario, we will select row 28 instead, as the 'Order Quantity' value appears to be much lower and the 'Order Amount' value appears to be close to each other. In a different scenario, when rows 29 and 30 have the same 'Patient ID' we would choose row 30 since its 'Order Amount' value is substantially lower and its 'Order Quantity' values differ from those of row 30 by less than 'Order Amount'. Rows 32 and 33 would be the alternative example. If the values for 'Order Amount' and 'Order Quantity' are the same, we can select row 32 as the first row between the two. We will choose the single row, if there is only one exception. Row 31 is one example.

[image: img3]

4. Plotting the points together for 'Order Amount' plotted against 'Order Time' and 'Order Quantity' plotted against 'Order Time' for each individual patient ID. This means one plot per patient ID.

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import urllib
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

input_date = input("Enter a date (format: yyyy/mm/dd): ")
input_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(input_date, "%Y/%m/%d")

df['Order Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Order Time'])

df['time_diff'] = (df['Order Time'] - input_date).dt.days

df_filtered = df[(df['time_diff'] >= -30) & (df['time_diff'] <= 30)]

recent_data = df_filtered.sort_values(by='Order Time').groupby('Patient ID').last()

merged_data = pd.merge(df, recent_data, on='Patient ID', suffixes=('_prev', ''))

## It seems okay up till this point, even though it is weird to include suffixes as '_prev'.

idx_amount = merged_data.groupby('Patient ID')['Order Amount'].idxmax()
idx_quantity = merged_data.groupby('Patient ID')['Order Quantity'].idxmax()

idx_highest = idx_amount[idx_amount.isin(idx_quantity)]

filtered_data = merged_data.loc[idx_highest]

def plot_filtered_data(data):

    grouped_data = data.groupby('Patient ID')
    
    for patient_id, group_data in grouped_data:
        plt.plot(group_data['Order Time'], group_data['Order Amount'], marker='o', label=f'Patient {patient_id}')
    
    plt.xlabel('Order Time')
    plt.ylabel('Order Amount')
    plt.title('Order Amount vs Order Time for Patients')
    plt.legend()
    plt.xticks(rotation=45)  
    plt.tight_layout()  
    plt.show()

plot_filtered_data(filtered_data)
```

I am aware that there is a mistake in the code, but I have little editing experience. Can someone point out my mistake? I know it can sound a bit complicated.